# Google Cloud Function without billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way I can create a demo cloud function without billing account? Billing account requires a credit card/ debit card to be entered in the billing profile.

My usage will be well under free quota.

Answer (score 1):

Billing account is required in order to use the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-tier) on GCP. As of now there is also [free usage quota](https://cloud.google.com/free/) including the Cloud Functions and Cloud Pub/Sub. If your usage be within the quotas the consumption won't be deducted from your free credits.

Comment: Don't thin appengine standard free tier needs a billing account.

Comment: Well, it states in the link provided: 
"Who's eligible for the free trial?
You have enabled billing for your account through Google Cloud Platform Console."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Functions free through Firebase as described by its [Spark plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), which doesn't require any billing.  Cloud Functions is included with this, but you can't do outbound networking to destinations not fully controlled by Google.

Comment: Outbound calls are not a problem. Firebase function 's syntax is still bit different than GCP cloud functions which I waned to use integrating with other GCP services like pubsu.